# How do I scrape all the bold section titles using scrapy in this webpage?

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

So I want to scrape all the bold section titles in this webpage eg. Short title, Interpretation, Administration of Act... but so far I can only do so for the first 2 in Part I.

```
import scrapy

class ActScraper1Spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'act_scraper_1'
    allowed_domains = ['sso.agc.gov.sg']
    start_urls = ['https://sso.agc.gov.sg/Act/AA2004']

def parse(self, response):

    info = response.xpath("//div[@class='body']/table//td[@class='part']/div[@class='prov1']")

    for titles in info:

        yield {
            'Section title': titles.xpath(".//td[@class='prov1Hdr']/span[2]/text()").get()
        }
```

There are altogether 8 parts contained in this webpage as seen from the 8 //table[@width='100%']
[image]

The titles are located here //div[@class='body']/table//td[@class='part']/div[@class='prov1']/td[@class='prov1Hdr']/span/text()
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this, just copy xpath from browser then paste in yield section for the title that you want.

```
import scrapy

class ActScraper1Spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'act_scraper_1'
    allowed_domains = ['sso.agc.gov.sg']
    start_urls = ['https://sso.agc.gov.sg/Act/AA2004']

    def parse(self, response):
        info = response.xpath("//*[@id='tocNav']")
        titles = info.xpath("//li/a/span/text()").getall()
        # all title
        # for title in titles:
        #     print(title.strip())
        for i in info:

                yield {
                    'short title': i.xpath('//*[@id="toc"]/li[4]/ul/li[1]/a/span/text()').get().strip(),
                    'Interpretation title2': i.xpath('//*[@id="toc"]/li[4]/ul/li[2]/a/span/text()').get().strip(),
                    'Administration of Act title2': i.xpath('//*[@id="toc"]/li[5]/ul/li[1]/a/span/text()').get().strip(),
                }
```